# how to count least used words

Tags: python, frequency

`wList` is a list that contains [(frequency of word, word)] in a text.
I want to know that words are used least frequently.
However, when I run the following code, I get

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

please tell me what I did wrong

```
def countLeastWds(wList) :
    cnt = 0
    leastUsed = 1
    leastUsed = wList[(-1)]
    wList.reverse()
    for fq in wList :
        if fq != leastUsed :
        break
        else : cnt = cnt + 1
return leastUsed, cnt
```

Comment: The indentation is wrong, at least for the final line. You also do not show a particular parameter value (for `wList`) that causes the error or the entire traceback for the error. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

d=dict([(2,'hello'),(3,'bye'),(1,'there')])
print collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items())).popitem(last=False)

Output: (1, 'there')
```